# After reviewing 50 edits I can't approve an edit to my own answer

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, voting-limits

This one is pretty straight forward. Earlier today I reviewed 50 proposed edits. After doing so another member suggested an edit to one of my answers to correct a minor mistake I had made. I tried to approve it but was rejected for using up all of my votes for the day.

The 50 vote limit shouldn't apply to your own answers and questions (especially when your rep is >25k).

Comment: Since you can single-handedly approve suggested edits to your own answers, it makes sense that they shouldn't be subject to the voting limit.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think in the following way :

The reason you edit the answer is mainly because of two things:

1. The author of the  post has not made the questions clear with respect to the constraints, purpose, and progress
2. The members replying the post has yet to read the questions clear before answering

Stack Overflow is a well-known portal and open platform for sharing and discussion among different areas especially on Information Technology and other expertise.   To solve the problem related to the expertise and profession, the quality and completeness for both questions and answers are important. Such policy can provide higher incentive for both author and replying members to raise discussion with high quality and consistency.

Sometimes, the vote count should not include voting your own answers and questions for all reputations in order to ensure your post is readable and high value for references in future.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunatly, the way that SO is coded allows you to suggest an edit, then gives you a weighted approval vote. However, it does send an approval request, even though it immediatly accepts it. This checks with the server if you may send a request, then sends it or rejects it based on the server feedback.

Since it asks the server first, if all your approval requests for the day are used, then it denies automatically.

I agree, however, to skip the server test for remaining votes and automatically allow edits (maybe make them not count to the total? IDK how SO would approach this) if you posted the question/answer that you are attempting to edit.

NOTE: I do not know the exact method that SO is coded in, but rather I am using logic and programming experience to provide a likely method that would fit the facts that you have showed.

Comment: uugh, I hate using SO on my phone. meant to put in comments.