# I should be able to review suggested edits to my own posts even if I've hit the review cap

Tags: feature-request, review, edits, suggested-edits

I believe that I should be able to review suggested edits to my own posts even if my suggested edit limit is hit. Furthermore, I believe that reviewing suggested edits to my own post (when I have not yet hit my limit) should not count towards my review limit.

I understand and support the general suggested edit limit, but I do not believe this should affect my ability to have a say on my own posts.

The workaround is for me to wait for the suggested edit to be approved/rejected, and then go back and edit my post myself. That is a functional workaround (except it can't be done immediately, I have to spend time repeatedly checking and waiting for the reject/approve), but I dislike SO's general model of forcing people use trivial but inconvenient workarounds rather than updating the rules to make workarounds unnecessary (other examples: editing another user's post to get around vote undo time limit, inserting html comments to get around minimum length / substance restrictions).

Comment: Related but not specifically on-topic: Additionally, I believe that my review of suggested edits to my own posts should be final (for that edit) rather than counting towards a vote. I have that power anyways (by editing my post after suggested edit is applied), I see no reason to force a workaround there either.

Comment: If you notice a suggested edit before others approve/reject it in the review queue, your vote in that regard is binding and approves/rejects the edit immediately...

Comment: @JonClements Thanks Jon, I did not realize that. Coincidentally, I haven't had a chance to experience that yet since I'm usually at my review limit and can't vote anyways.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read over my comment again. Users without the "edit anywhere" can approve/decline suggested edits on their own posts, and their vote is binding.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn this potentially leads to a weird situation where a robo-approver approves some vandalism to his own post and doesn't even notice his post was edited.

Comment: @JanDvorak That's how it works now, and that issue doesn't seem to exist. Somebody will report it, or he will notice a lot of down votes, and soon enough the problem will solve itself. That also relies on this type of person coincidentally encountering their own post when working through reviews. A person who is responding to a "somebody suggested an edit on your post" notification is unlikely to "robo approve" it. This issue you describe is so rare (think of everything that must line up for that to happen) and inconsequential (yes, it is) that I'm not sure it should impact any decisions here.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139286/192262 ?